# Is it possible to show road restrictions on the map?

Tags: flutter, here-api

Is there a layer to show road restrictions on the map especially for trucks?
I'm using the Here Flutter Navigation SDK 4.6

Another question: given a position and a direction, is it possible to know if there are ahead restrictions, for example max height 2.5 meters or max weight, etc., using the Here SDK or APIs?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be available for the [Maps API for JavaScript](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/truck-routing-road-restrictions). Such a layer is not yet available for the HERE SDK for Flutter.